# How to change sql backline to html backline

Tags: html, sql

So my problem is that I have a field where I can put text which is converted by some batch process before stored in database. Due to that in case I would insert text like below the DB will get only first line.

```
    test

    test

    test

    test
```

How could I change end of line to match html format using SQL syntax?

Comment: If it was me, I would keep the newlines in your database and make the corrections in your presentation layer. That way if you decided to write the data to a flat file, you would not then need to deal with embedded html tags polluting your data. It is likely fairly easy to wrap a <pre /> around your text and get the result you want with newlines in the data.

Comment: The problem is that when presentation layer works fine. If DB store text with multiple lines display in my application is correct. But after I put text in field in application (comment in that case) batch process read next line as a new parameter instead of full text and then uptade table in DB with only first line

Comment: What's a *backline*?

Comment: I think he means return, newline, carriage feed, \r, \n, etc.